# Background drawable not applying to button

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I am trying to create a capsule/pill shaped button in XML.  I have defined a drawable and set it as the background of my button, but in the preview, and when I run the app, it's displaying as a blue rectangle, despite the background drawable being a white oval.  Does anyone know why that might be happening?

Here's the button:

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/search_box"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_capsule"
            android:text="@string/search"
            android:textColor="@color/precipLightBlue"/>
```

And here's the background drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="1000dp" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

</shape>
```

Comment: can you add an image? so we can understand what's an actual issue in that

Answer (score 1):

To have a capsule/pill shaped button you can use the [**`MaterialButton`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) in the official [Material Component library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) using the `app:cornerRadius` attribute.

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            app:cornerRadius="32dp"
            ..../>
```

With the version 1.1.0 you can also [customize the shape](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) of your component using the `app:shapeAppearanceOverlay` attribute

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
     ....
     app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.ButtonRounded"
     .../>
```

In the style define:

```
 <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.ButtonRounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">32dp</item>
 </style>
```

[image]

You can also try to use the [`ExtendedFloatingActionButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/ExtendedFloatingActionButton.md):

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/exfab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        .... />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You put a shape that you didn't defined. To define an oval you should put the shape="oval" option in the  tag. Although i think you want a rectangle with rounded corners as i see in your code.

Also 1000dp radius is a lot, maybe that's making an issue. 
Define size too. Because that shape doesn't have any size and may not appear as you are using wrap_content in the button definition

Try this:

```
<corners android:radius="30dp" />

<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

<size
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="50dp"/>
```

If you want an oval remove the corners tag and add android:shape="oval" as property of shape tag

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code regarding button drawable background.

**Xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center|top"
android:background="@color/colorLightPurple">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:text="Search"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

For button background , please add same drawable file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

seems like you're doing everything right. Just a small addition, try adding `android:shape="rectangle"` in the shape tag.

This is what **button_capsule.xml** should look like.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="1000dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Hope this works. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

In **Material design version 1.2.0** they have fixed this issue and added a property for setting background for Material Button
here is the dependency for the latest version

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0
```

and also if u want to remove the space between the drawable top and bottom so that the drawable get the whole width and height use these 2 properties

```
    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:insetBottom="0dp"
```

if want to explore more about the properties u can refer to the release of library and can check all the properties.

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.2.0

Answer (score -1):

use this.

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
.....
/>